# Rerender Datatable in Angular after updated Data in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, render, rerender

I´ve got a cockpit in my app with different D3-charts and Datatables in Angular, distributed over three tabs. 
All the data comes from an API and is used with Datapromises.
The customer wants to have the ability to filter the data for example with a specific projectNr. The filtering is also done with the API, so the app will send a request again with the correct parameters.

**This all works fine in Chrome 56.0, Firefox 51.0.1 and Safari 10.0.2**

The problem occurs in Internet Explorer 11 (probably other IE versions as well)

I will tell you the workflow how it is run through in Chrome.

[image: Console Logs]

The blue logs are just JavaScript `console.time()`.
The `HTTP.GET` and `GOT` logs are from our ApiService for every fired API request. 
So now you see with the first visit on the cockpit we get the Request `allManagerData`. This requests gets all the data we need to fill the charts and tables on cockpit. 
Then we have some autocomplete inputs, which are bounded to the API. This API call `recordsearch` gets the select-options for the autocomplete-input. 
When choosing an object out of the autocomplete-input the filter-logic starts. It is actually the same, like the initial loading, just the API request got an other parameter with the correct filter Value. After the second `allManagerData` request comes back, all the datatables and charts will be rerendered.

This works fine, but not in IE!
Here is the console when exactly the same inputs are made from IE11.

[image]

You see the rerender-Functions are called correctly with the initial request, but with the second request it crashes with the first rerendering. Does not care which one is the first, it is the first `DataTable.rerender()` In both cases (initial and after filtering) the rerender will be called with `$cockpit.rerenderDataTables();`

```js
$cockpit.rerenderDataTables = function () {
  if ($cockpit.dtStars.DataTable) {
    console.log('rerenderTable 1');
    $cockpit.dtStars.rerender();
  }
  if ($cockpit.dtNote10.DataTable) {
    console.log('rerenderTable 2');
    $cockpit.dtNote10.rerender();
  }
  if ($cockpit.dtYesNo.DataTable) {
    console.log('rerenderTable 3');
    $cockpit.dtYesNo.rerender();
  }
  if ($cockpit.dtProjects.DataTable) {
    console.log('rerenderTable 4');
    $cockpit.dtProjects.rerender();
  }
};
```

The datatables in frontend are the following:

`<table datatable="ng" dt-options="$cockpit.dtConfig.dtOptions" class="row-border stripe hover" dt-instance="$cockpit.dtStars">`

I really have no idea what is wrong with the `.rerender()` Function in IE11.

Anybody also uses the Angular1 Datatables and has problems with rerendering on IE?
Or any other ideas?

Thank you!